# Make HTTP Request from Verilog

Tags: c++, python, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Is it possible to call a C/C++/Python/Java function that makes an HTTP request inside of a Verilog module?

Comment: Are you looking to do this in actual hardware or only in a simulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, do some searching for 'DPI' or 'PLI'.  If you have a SystemVerilog capable simulator the DPI solution is a lot less overhead.  Basically the Verilog end of it will be:

```
import "DPI" function void do_http(...)
```

Where you can then call do_http within your Verilog like a normal task or function and you pass the .c file that implements do_http on the command line along with the rest of your sources.  This of course is assuming that you're using a commercial Verilog simulator.  I don't think Icarus supports DPI yet (could be wrong).

Using VPI is a more portable but takes significantly more coding to put together.  I encourage you to research that one on your own if that's what you need.